# Using PSPDFKit with Ionic 2

Tags: cordova, ionic2, pspdfkit

I am struggling to use PSPDFKit with Ionic 2. I have added cordova and referenced the PSPDFKitPlugin.

I tried adding the following line to the top of the '.ts' file in which I am calling the PSPDFKit from.

```
declare var cordova: any;
```

Then in the event within the file I added this code below:

```
let fileNative = new File();
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  cordova.PSPDFKitPlugin.setLicenseKey('KEY');
  cordova.PSPDFKitPlugin.present(`${fileNative.dataDirectory}/${file.name}`, {
    pageTransition: 'curl',
    pageMode: 'double',
    backgroundColor: 'red'
  });
});
```

When inspecting the simulator's console logs via Safari's remote debugger the following error appears:

```
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'cordova.PSPDFKitPlugin.setLicenseKey')
```

Comment: Hey, have you found any solution, I also need that.

Comment: Any solution. There is only Ionic 1 support on their site?